# VS can't use .net package

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I followed the steps to install the version of asp.net core 3.1, then I can't open the project when I open VS to use. So I checked to see if the version was installed correctly and it showed that it couldn't find any installed dotnet SDK, why? I'm sure the version of asp.net core 3.1 is already installed.

Comment: Is this VS Code, VS 2019/2022, or VS for Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does it mean that the project cannot be opened using VS? You created the project can't display the file directory, is that so? It is possible that you did not install the SDK correctly.

The easiest way:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet

You click to download the version you downloaded before, and then when you install it, if you already have this version of the SDK, an uninstall button will appear. You try to click uninstall and then reinstall. I tried it and it worked for me.

If you don't want to use this method and want to fix it manually, you can refer to this article:

https://github-wiki-see.page/m/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Troubleshooting%3A-%27The-.NET-Core-SDK-cannot-be-located.%27-errors

Comment: Yes, it worked for me to reinstall. But why is there a problem the first time. . I'm weird.